# Cassandra COPY FROM loses lots of rows

Tags: csv, import, cassandra

I'm trying to figure out why I'm losing data when I load from a CSV file using `COPY FROM`.  Here's my setup:

```
% cat /tmp/data 
2-54-2014,"2014-01-01T01:00:00Z","1588.6960767"
2-54-2014,"2014-01-01T01:10:00Z","1587.64072333"
2-54-2014,"2014-01-01T01:20:00Z","1590.48448448"
2-54-2014,"2014-01-01T01:30:00Z","1590.72830295"
2-54-2014,"2014-01-01T01:40:00Z","1582.58896162"
2-54-2014,"2014-01-01T01:50:00Z","1569.62739561"
2-54-2014,"2014-01-01T02:00:00Z","1560.63714579"
2-54-2014,"2014-01-01T02:10:00Z","1551.97991093"
2-54-2014,"2014-01-01T02:20:00Z","1576.29093944"
2-54-2014,"2014-01-01T02:30:00Z","1584.34574486"

% cqlsh -k hats                                                           
Connected to Test Cluster at 127.0.0.1:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.10 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]
Use HELP for help.
cqlsh:hats> CREATE TABLE power_1turb (
            id TEXT, ts TIMESTAMP, value DOUBLE, PRIMARY KEY ((id), ts));
```

Now I try to load the data file into Cassandra:

```
cqlsh:hats> COPY power_1turb (id, ts, value) FROM '/tmp/data';
Using 7 child processes

Starting copy of hats.power_1turb with columns [id, ts, value].
Processed: 10 rows; Rate:      16 rows/s; Avg. rate:      24 rows/s
10 rows imported from 1 files in 0.412 seconds (0 skipped).


cqlsh:hats> select * from power_1turb ;

 id        | ts                              | value
-----------+---------------------------------+------------
 2-54-2014 | 2013-12-31 18:00:00.000000+0000 | 1560.63715

(1 rows)
```

Why is it only loading 1 row, and why is it always this same row in the middle of the data?  If I run a few queries like `insert into power_1turb (id, ts, value) values ('2-54-2014','2014-01-01T01:30:00Z',1590.72830295);`, they do populate to the database just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Define datetimeformat along with copy command**

Because your datetime format is not matching with cqlsh default datetime format

For your case use the below copy command :

```
COPY power_1turb (id, ts, value) FROM 'data' WITH DATETIMEFORMAT = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ';
```

Tested with Cqlsh of `Cassandra 2.2.5`

```
cassandra@cqlsh:test> SELECT * FROM power_1turb ;

 id        | ts                       | value
-----------+--------------------------+------------
 2-54-2014 | 2014-01-01 01:00:00+0000 | 1588.69608
 2-54-2014 | 2014-01-01 01:10:00+0000 | 1587.64072
 2-54-2014 | 2014-01-01 01:20:00+0000 | 1590.48448
 2-54-2014 | 2014-01-01 01:30:00+0000 |  1590.7283
 2-54-2014 | 2014-01-01 01:40:00+0000 | 1582.58896
 2-54-2014 | 2014-01-01 01:50:00+0000 |  1569.6274
 2-54-2014 | 2014-01-01 02:00:00+0000 | 1560.63715
 2-54-2014 | 2014-01-01 02:10:00+0000 | 1551.97991
 2-54-2014 | 2014-01-01 02:20:00+0000 | 1576.29094
 2-54-2014 | 2014-01-01 02:30:00+0000 | 1584.34574

(10 rows)
```

Related doc For cassandra 2.2.5 cqlsh

> DATETIMEFORMAT, which used to be called TIMEFORMAT, a string containing the Python strftime format for date and time values, such as ‘%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z’. It defaults to the time_format value in cqlshrc.

Comment: Thanks, that did it.  I'm curious why one of the rows did parse successfully, though.  It's got the same format as everything else.  How can I show the default value of `time_format`?

Comment: Use `HELP copy` in cqlsh which will show you copy command help info along with DATETIMEFORMAT